# iMacros - WhatsApp Web

Tags: imacros

I'm working on a project that extracts a table from a webpage dashboard, then it goes to excel where it gets filtered by how many each user has in a nice table, and the next step I'm working on is having already in the clipboard the table I want to send it to our work group on whatsapp, specifically in chrome since it sends the tables as an image.

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" CHARS="Usuario Admin"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" KEYS=13
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>FOOTER>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* Char="V" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:btn<SP>btn-round<SP>btn-l&&TXT:
```

I used EVENT mode since the conventional mode didn't do anything

This script was working but then it stopped doing it, on Chrome instead of writing the group name on the search bar it does in the chat now:S
on Firefox, I need to have something written in the search bar(like a space) so it writes it there but the ENTER part doesn't always work.

Is there a way that ensures it writes where it should?, I tried something in javascript but it wrote it on search but it was like I had to type something so it searches what it was written, I hope I explained myself correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the search bar was very tricky, and worked when it wasn't empty I tried to write a space before the word and it worked:

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" CHARS=" Usuario Admin"
```

Comment: Hey @Norman Carrizo, I have just run into a brick wall with imacros. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532248/imacros-submitting-textarea-form-enter-key-maybe if you happen to know the answer you'd be my savior