# imacros: submitting textarea form (enter key maybe?)

Tags: imacros

**Question:** How to simulate an ENTER (to submit a text in a live chat)?
(if there is an alternative to using the ENTER key, like using javascript in imacros to trigger an event, that would be great too)

---

**Explanation:**

I am trying to submit a comment in a live chat that uses a `<textarea>` element for input. Here is the source code:

```
<form class="chatbox nolabel">
    <textarea class="textbox" type="text" size="70" autocomplete="off" name="message" style="resize: none; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
</form>
```

I have attempted various different approaches of inputting the word "hello" and pressing the ENTER key (so that hello is sent to the users reading), however the only thing I am capable of doing is inputting the word "hello".

**Attempt 1:**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:message CONTENT=hi
```

**Results from Attempt 1:**
When recording, this is the code that appeared when I started typing in the text area, and it successfully places the content into the `textarea`, however I didn't see any code being recorded when I press the ENTER key, so I assume that is the issue in this case.

**Attempt 2:** (event recording mode)

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>TEXTAREA:nth-of-type(2)" CHARS="hi"
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>TEXTAREA:nth-of-type(2)" KEY=13
```

**Results from Attempt 1:**
In this case, I tried using the Keypress type with events to simulate hitting the ENTER key, however what resulted was getting a "hi(newline)".

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @timfredo ! There isn't a button sadly. Regarding Directscreen, I am using firefox and the imacros page mentions it's only for internet explorer "http://wiki.imacros.net/DirectScreen_Technology". Regarding the commercial version, is that the "iMacros WebBrowser Component for .NET" from http://imacros.net/download ? I have heard that there is an iMacros browser, but after looking for a while, I wasn't able to find it on the iMacros website. I assume the iMacros browser is the commercial version you are referring to? And if you know where I can get it, I would love to know.

Comment: @timfredo awesome that worked! Though now for some reason I can't see the .js files I had made previously in firefox. I can see all the other files, though for some reason the imacros browser doesn't allow for creating code in .js like firefox does? Am I still able to use all the loops and other code I made in my .js files in the imacros browser some how?

Comment: @timfredo oh I see. So with the iMacros browser is it possible to write a file in another language's code (do looping among other things) then call iimPlay() and use those scripting interface commands from that page? (if possible, how might I be able to create the file that does it? In firefox, just renaming the #current.iim into something like test.js and then playing the js file was how I did it, though the iMacros browser doesn't seem to allow altering of the iim extension). Or do the loops and all the intricate stuff have to use a native language created for iMacros?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132712/discussion-between-webeng-and-timfredo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes other key event types may help:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>TEXTAREA:nth-of-type(2)" KEY=13
```

or

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYUP SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>TEXTAREA:nth-of-type(2)" KEY=13
```

Comment: that was a simple and beautiful solution.